# Populating and Hiding/Showing States Drop down based on Country selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a working code for populating States drop down list with an array based on Country drop down list selected value and I would like to add something like Jquery `show() and hide()` to hide the states drop down if the country is not included in the array of `"countryStateArray"` and do the opposite while populating the states list

here is my code on Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Av2d7/

Thank you

Comment: You made it, what is problem?

Comment: i remember fixing it and posting it in comments few days ago... what you've is the fixed version... so..?

Comment: can you explain how the accepted answer fixed the problem..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should change the array of arrays into an object. This will make it much easier to find the states by related key:

```
var countryStateArray = {
    'US': [
        ['', 'State/Province'],
        ['AL', 'Alabama'],
        ['AK', 'Alaska'],
        /* And so on... */
    ],
    'CA': [
        ['', 'State/Province'],
        ['AB', 'Alberta'],
        ['BC', 'British Columbia'],
        ['MB', 'Manitoba'],
        /* And so on... */
    ],
    'AU': [
        ['', 'State/Province'],
        ['ACT', 'Australian Capital Terr.'],
        ['NSW', 'New South Wales'],
        /* And so on... */
    ]
};
```

You can then use the value of `#countryId` to find the country key within the object. If it exists you can loop through the states contained therein and append them to `#stateId` and show it. If the key does not exists you can hide the states select.

As you are using jQuery anyway, you should use it to attach your events as it is a better separation of concerns over using outdated `on*` attributes in HTML:

```
#stateId { display: none; }
```

```js
function setStates() {
    var $country = $('#countryId');
    var $state = $('#stateId');
    var countryId = $country.val();

    if (countryStateArray[countryId]) {
        // states exist for this country, append them and show the select
        for (var i = 0; i < countryStateArray[countryId].length; i++) {
            var state = countryStateArray[countryId][i];
            $('<option />', { value: state[0], text: state[1] }).appendTo($state);
        }
        $state.show();
    } else {
        // no states, empty the select and hide it
        $state.empty().hide();
    }
}

setStates(); // onload
$('#countryId').change(setStates); // onchange
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Av2d7/1/)

Comment: The code is already working. This question was posted few days ago. The fiddle he shared is the working code (*fixed version of his own code*) he got from the responses. So, how does your answer fix the issue..? or, what's actually teh issue..?

Comment: @TilwinJoy He asked how to incorporate hiding and showing the states box, depending on if there are any to be shown. I also improved the code by making it much shorter.

Comment: "He asked how to incorporate hiding and showing the states box, depending on if there are any to be shown" - that part is already working. So there's no problem statement in the question. I'd consider answering it if there's at least something like *how can i improve this code*..? or should be redirected to code review... idk. never mind.

Comment: Thank You Rory for your great help this code is spotless

Comment: @TilwinJoy your concern with my question is very weird just get over it

Comment: @user3759159 it's not very weird because i'm the guy who fixed that code few days ago. i don't know why it came back without even a problem statement. and your question doesn't belong to so since it doesn't have a problem statement. hence my concern as an active stackoverflow user.

Comment: I wasn't asking for fixing it may be it was a little buggy but it was working I was asking for how to include a show() and hide() states select based on the code